# copying my backup files

Tags: backup

I've made a backup.tgz file of all my work, which is now in the root directory. Can someone tell me the best way to copy it to an external hard drive? I'm guessing move it to the desktop, mount the external drive then just copy across... but the exact code would be useful.

(NB. I made the backup.tgz following a procedure from a couple of years ago, but don't have tech support any more. I'm working in an older version of Ubuntu, running Koha, wanting to upgrade to a newer version and backing everything up first, just in case.)

Comment: You got two options: Do it manually: copy/paste or by using command-line and `sudo mv` [move] or `sudo cp` [copy] command with root/su privileges.

Comment: @v2r no reason to use `sudo` unless the target is owned by root.

Answer (score 0):

Keep backup.tgz on dir you wish. Then use terminal to copy the file.

> cp -b PathToTgz PathToExternalDrive

I would use something like:

> cp -b /backup.tgz /media/UserName/HardDriveLabel

to keep it on external HDD root dir.